# Adding fields to notification php object

Tags: php, firebase-cloud-messaging

I started developing an app that has push notifications in it. I want my notification object to hold a message and other extra string that I call "color".

Everything worked well until I added the row 'data'=>$color. Now my message field is empty (null) and I can only read the color string.

How to add more data field to the PHP fields array?

```
function send_notification ($tokens, $message, $color)
{
    $url = 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send';
    $fields = array(
         'registration_ids' => $tokens,
         'data' => $message,
         'data' => $color
        );
    $headers = array(
        'Authorization:key = Not telling you me real key :)',                        
        'Content-Type: application/json'
        );
   $ch = curl_init();
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
   curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);  
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($fields));
   $result = curl_exec($ch);           
   if ($result === FALSE) {
       die('Curl failed: ' . curl_error($ch));
   }
   curl_close($ch);
   return $result;
}
```

Comment: You can not add two values with the same key. In this case the key is 'data'. If you rename one of them to something else it should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either change the field name, so it will be like `'color' => $color`, or you can append it to the `data` field. It will be something like this:

```
$data = $message . "\n";
$data .= $color;
```

Edit: I believe your `$message` variabile might be a json, so you should append the `$color` to that json.